# Jenkins 403 Error: No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jenkins

I have changed my Jenkin's security policy from "Anyone can do anything" to "Logged in users can do anything".

This logged me out and bought me to the login page. When I enter my credentials I am taken to the `/j_acegi_security_check` webpage and am told the following:

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
URI:    /j_acegi_security_check
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    No valid crumb was included in the request
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

I have tried accessing the machine through my regular means via the web address and also through SSH i.e. `ssh -L 1234:localhost:8080 <username>@<web address>`. Both result in the same page.

I installed Jenkins some time ago with apt and was running find until I made the security change. Please help as I am unable to access the pipelines and everything else inside.

Comment: Have you looked at https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039598171-Navigation-in-Jenkins-fails-with-No-valid-crumb-was-included-in-request-errors
What have you tried to do in order to fix this?

Comment: @apr_1985 thanks for your comment. I am unable to access anything other than the login page. My searches were unsuccessful as all remedies I saw were similar to what you linked, which doesn't help me as I cannot access that page within Jenkins.

Comment: SSH onto the master node open the `config.xml` file and change `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`.  Then restart the Jenkins service/process/box and Jenkins should come back up with security disabled so you can get back in to set config as you need

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue that Jenkins logged me out after I changed security policy, and hit 403 when I tried to login. That is because I change "Security Realm" from "Jenkins’ own user database" to other options. Change that setting back fix the login issue.

Comment: Thanks for this! This was also my issue, though somehow this setting was automatically disabled since I never touched it. EDIT: Maybe it gets auto-disabled when you turn `useSecurity` off in config.xml, which I needed to do temporarily?

Comment: This answer saved my day. Like Manningham, I once turn `useSecurity` off and the error happened, because some how the `Security Realm` is being rested.