# Jenkins update 2.289 login error : HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jenkins, updates

I updated Jenkins to version 2.289.2 and restarted an application. It started correctly and I was able to get to the Dashboard page. However when I am trying to login I am getting this message :

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
URI:    /j_spring_security_check
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    No valid crumb was included in the request
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

how do I fix it??

Comment: You probably had a Jenkins tab open elsewhere. Exit browser, come back in.

Comment: It didn't work. I closed all the browsers and got the same message.

Comment: Then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071774/jenkins-403-error-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was fixed by browsing manually to `https://<myJenkinsInstance>/logout`

After that the login worked again.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response .
http://server:8080/logout
After this ask to pass initialAdmin Password put and will start working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).